# UIScrollView not scroll auto layout issues

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6, autolayout, ios-autolayout

I never used auto layouts in my life and it was great time, now storyboard take off my brain.

The conception maybe is not bad. But it's still buggy and worst to use. I have worked for today and spend 8 hours to setup one scroll view and few subviews. Does it save time???

If Apple wants to support adoptive design. Why they don't use Edge Reflow conception. It is for web, but it's great and without bugs....

I have scroll view with all needed constraints, it means that the scroll view size will be the same as superview.

I am trying to change scroll view content size in `-viewDidLoad` method:

```
[self.theScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, 20000)];
```

but seems it want work.

Print out says that the content size is 320 20000, but I can scroll it.

Answer (score 0):

With autolayout, you have to do things bottom-up and implicitly;  in other words, instead of telling the scrollView how big its content is, you let the scrollView adjust itself based on the size of its content.  This allows the autolayout to resolve the constraints between subviews and propagate the changes upward.

If you want to explicitly set the content size, you could create an additional subview containing all the content of the scrollView, and then override its intrinsicContentSize method to explicitly tell the scrollView how big it is.

Comment: thank you for answer. I also find a solution where as a suggestion we add content view. Pin it to the all sides. Then make height of content view higher and update constrains.

Answer (score 0):

Working tried out.

if you are **not** using autolayout then put it only **viewDidLoad()**:

```
[_mainScroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 2000)];
```

or if you are using **autolayout** then follow this:

First give **constrains** to scrollview top,bottom,leading and trailing.
Now take one more view and give same constrains as scrollview given by you earlier.

Don't forgot to give additional constrain for that view **fix height** and **width equal** to main parent view.

or

**Just watch this**.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rjTS9fyWqdg